# UK Visit Visa - Payment is being processed

Tags: visas, uk, payment

I'm planning to visit my husband's family and friends in the UK in a couple of months. I have all the required documents.

I did the online application. Unfortunately in the last minutes/payment section, after I put my bank details, I didn't get any confirmation until now. It's been two days and my appointment for documents submission will be in the next three days.

Is it because I applied on a weekend? Or will it be confirmed during weekdays?
I need some advice and suggestions, please.

Comment: "I didn't get any confirmation till now" - just to clarify, you have now received confirmation? And this was in the form of an email? Was there no confirmation at all at the end of the online application? No reference number?

Comment: I have not received anything yet, its been 3 days now, and my appointment supposed to be in a couple days. I'm assuming its because weekend+easter holiday, will keep checking my email and payment status, and update on here.

Comment: You still have not explained things clearly. You have not explained the whole sequence of events.  You have not made clear who has given you the appointment and what you attempted to do online.  The Easter weekend may well have brought everything to a standstill, but one thing for sure, you must be very clear not just in what you explain to us but what you put forward in your application.